# What are the implied differences in わたくし and わたし?

Tags: readings, colloquial-language

Although I believe わたし to be the more common reading of 私, I have heard many examples of わたくし being used as well (ex 黒澤ダイア ラブライブ). Does that mean わたくし is an informal version or more feminine version of わたし, like あたし? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

わたくし is a very formal 'version' of 私, and is used by all genders.

Comment: In addition, I was taught that in a professional/formal environment where you're gonna use keigo, when introducing yourself you should use わたくし at least the first time you refer to yourself: 「わたくし、A社の○○と申します」

Comment: I never used わたくし in professional setting, though. Teachers like to set too many boundaries and rules to ‘protect’ you, in my opinion. You should be able to make your own judgement for when it’s too polite or not.

Answer (score -1):

わたし is polite.

わたくし is more polite than わたし.

Both are used by all genders.